# How to add a function that creates a link to os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/') in settings.py django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I use froala editor to add text to the model and I want to change the folder where the images will be loaded from the form field.
My function to create a path looks like this:

```
#utilities.py
def article_img_directory_path(instance, filename):
    article_title = slugify(instance.title, allow_unicode=True)
    return 'images/{0}/{1}'.format(article_title, filename)
```

I don't know how to add this function to the editor's path correctly:

```
#settings.py
from articles.utilities import article_img_directory_path

FROALA_UPLOAD_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')+str(article_img_directory_path)
```

Images are loaded and displayed, but as a result, the loading path is wrong

Answer (score 1):

I ain't got the reputation to comment, but see are you using your models to save those files?

If yes,

use the upload_to attribute of FileField in your model and point it to article_img_directory_path, then automatically, all your files will be saved in your desired location.

If No,

I don't clearly get what you are trying to accomplish here, but
os.path.join(base_dir, 'media/') returns you the string path of the media folder.

You are trying to concatenate the bound method of your function here, not even invoking the function by using (). You gotta invoke the function by calling it and passing the arguments there. But I doubt that it will work from settings.py where you cannot access any instance.

So, I suggest you to look at the FileField and upload_to here [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#:~:text=def%20user_directory_path(instance%2C%20filename)%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20file%20will%20be%20uploaded%20to%20MEDIA_ROOT/user_%3Cid%3E/%3Cfilename%3E%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%27user_%7B0%7D/%7B1%7D%27.format(instance.user.id%2C%20filename)%0A%0Aclass%20MyModel(models.Model)%3A%0A%20%20%20%20upload%20%3D%20models.FileField(upload_to%3Duser_directory_path)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#:%7E:text=def%20user_directory_path(instance%2C%20filename)%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20file%20will%20be%20uploaded%20to%20MEDIA_ROOT/user_%3Cid%3E/%3Cfilename%3E%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%27user_%7B0%7D/%7B1%7D%27.format(instance.user.id%2C%20filename)%0A%0Aclass%20MyModel(models.Model)%3A%0A%20%20%20%20upload%20%3D%20models.FileField(upload_to%3Duser_directory_path))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).